# Oracle Query is not executing for Large volume without Stat Gathering even if the plan is good

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-performance

Im processing a large volume using batch process ,Batch got stuck at particular query which involve a table (table is permanent but using for holding data temporary, table data will clear after processing ).Query plan was good and cost is very less .  If i gathered the table and index stat with the data and lock it  , query executes in seconds . But Query will again stuck when different nature of data comes. Is there any option available other than stat gathering to work this out .

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try to use dynamic sampling (or dynamic statistics as the feature is labeled since Version 12): https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/dynamic-sampling-and-its-impact-on-the-optimizer. This would allow you to gather the statistics for every execution using a dynamic_sampling hint in your call.